# Implementar método para leer código de barras en Java

Tags: java, scanner

Quiero buscar documentación para poder implementar un método en mi programa de Java que a la hora de leer un código de barras con mi escáner físico me guarde el código leído en un `String`. Una vez leído ya no tendría problema para buscarlo en la base de datos y mostrar el producto.

Me estoy intentando ayudar con este ejemplo http://empezandoconjava.blogspot.com.es/2012/01/clase-scanner-en-java.html .

Comment: ¿Tienes algo de código para mostrarnos?

Comment: Me estoy intentando ayudar con este ejemplo http://empezandoconjava.blogspot.com.es/2012/01/clase-scanner-en-java.html si consigo implementarlo lo compartiré

Comment: Sería importante que mencionaras sí los códigos de barra son generados por ti o si son de un tercero, además podrías agregar el código que llevas.

Comment: El escaner de código de barras se considera un teclado, por lo que para leer simplemente escanea el código. ¿Tu aplicación será web o swing (Interfaz gráfica)? Si es modo consola con la clase Scanner te funcionará, ya que el escaner físico es considerado un teclado.

Comment: Sería en Swing, me gustaría que se pulsara un botón y que se pusiera en espera mientras espera que pase el cógido de barras por el lector físico, me imagino que será utilizando eventos

Comment: Como te digo el Escaner de código de barras es considerado un teclado por lo que no deberías hacerle más... si tu quisieras otra lógica creo que tu pregunta deberías modificar, puesto que la respuesta es simple, tu solo utiliza tu escaner como teclado y ya.

Comment: tendrias que usar para las funciones de eventos que se generan en java al utilizar teclado ya que el scaner una vez que lo utilices enviara el numero de codigo de barras al evento teclado(una funcion de java) y de ahi tendrias que guardar el valor en una variable y listo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya he entendido como realizar el escaneo, se pulsa un Jbutton que haga un evento donde se encuentra el método jTextField.requestFocus(), entonces el foco se pone a parpadear en el jTextField y cuando el lector de código de barras lee el código aparece la enumeración en el jTextField, como el número se encuentra en el jTextField ya se puede buscar en la base de datos el número de dicho producto y mostrarlo por pantalla. No necesito para nada la librería Scanner.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que estás confundiendo conceptos. Una cosa es que quieras leer un código de barras a través de un escáner, y otra es la clase [**Scanner**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Scanner.html), que es capaz de leer texto con una determinada sintaxis muy básica desde consola o desde un archivo.

Tú estás interesado en una librería como [**zxing**](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Getting-Started-Developing), que te permitirá manejarte con códigos de barras.